# Function not defined when calling aictab

Tags: r, mass

I'm getting an error message when trying to generate an `aictab` table

**CODE**

```
library(MASS)
library(AICcmodavg)

set.seed(456)
d <- data.frame(ID = 1:20,
                Ct = c(sample(x = 1:50, size = 12, replace = T), rep(x = 0, length.out = 8)),
                V = as.factor(rep(x = c("Dry", "Wet"), each = 2)),
                S = as.factor(rep(x = c("Sand", "Clay"), each = 2)))

m1 <- glm.nb(Ct ~ 1, data = d)
m2 <- glm.nb(Ct ~ V, data = d)
m3 <- glm.nb(Ct ~ S, data = d)

all_ms <- list(m1, m2, m3)
names(all_ms) <- c("null", "type", "soil")

aic_tb <- aictab(cand.set = all_ms, second.ord = TRUE)
```

**OUTPUT**

> Error in aictab.default(cand.set = all_ms, second.ord = TRUE): Function not yet defined for this object class

Can anyone see why this is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `aictab()` seems unable to handle objects of class `negbin` (the result from `glm.nb()`).

An easy workaround is to use `glm.convert()` which modifies your output to look like one from `glm()` with a negative binomial family:

```
all_ms_glm <- lapply(all_ms, glm.convert)
aictab(cand.set = all_ms_glm, second.ord = TRUE)
# Model selection based on AICc:
#  
#      K   AICc Delta_AICc AICcWt Cum.Wt      LL
# null 2 396.34       0.00   0.35   0.35 -195.82
# soil 3 396.46       0.13   0.33   0.67 -194.48
# type 3 396.46       0.13   0.33   1.00 -194.48
```

Answer (score 1):

For the record this works in version 2.2-1: the [NEWS file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AICcmodavg/NEWS) suggests it was fixed in version 2.2-0.

> revision 2.2-0 (25 February 2019) 
>   ...
>   added methods for objects of 'glm.nb' class