# using aictab() for lmer and glmer models

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to do AICc model selection using `aictab()` output. This posting is similar ([Function not defined when calling aictab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909646/function-not-defined-when-calling-aictab)) but does not apply to my problem because it used `glm.nb` models and I am using `lmer` models and also `glmer(family=binomial)`. The `aictab` documentation (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AICcmodavg/versions/2.2-1/topics/aictab) says the function can handle `lm`, `lme` and `glm` models: does that include `lmer` and `glmer`?

My code actually worked a few days ago, but recently broke and returned this error code

> Error in aictab.default() : Function not yet defined for this object class

```
m1 <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|z), data=df)
m2 <- lmer(y ~ w + (1|z), data=df)
m3 <- lmer(y ~ v + (1|z), data=df)
cand.set <- list(m1, m2, m3)
names <- list("x", "w", "v")
aictab(cand.set, modnames=names, second.ord=TRUE, nobs=NULL, sort=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** you loaded the `lmerTest` package, so your models have a different class, which is confusing `aictab()`. You could either make sure you have `lme4` and *not* `lmerTest` loaded when you fit the models, or use `bbmle::AICctab()`, which seems slightly more robust.  (It might be worth contacting the package maintainer of `AICcmodavg` about this ...)

Set up with `lme4`:

```
library(lme4)
library(AICcmodavg)

ss <- transform(sleepstudy, junk1=rnorm(nrow(sleepstudy)),
                junk2=rnorm(nrow(sleepstudy)))
m1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data=ss, REML=FALSE)
m2 <- update(m1, . ~ . - Days + junk1)
m3 <- update(m1, . ~ . - Days + junk2)
cand.set <- list(m1, m2, m3)
names <- c("Days", "junk1", "junk2")  ## this should be a vector, not a list ...
```

This works fine:

```
aictab(cand.set, modnames=names, second.ord=TRUE, nobs=NULL, sort=TRUE)
##       K    AICc Delta_AICc AICcWt Cum.Wt      LL
## Days  4 1802.31       0.00      1      1 -897.04
## junk2 4 1918.47     116.16      0      1 -955.12
## junk1 4 1918.71     116.40      0      1 -955.24
```

Now load `lmerTest` and refit the models (we could just do e.g. `m1 <- as(m1, "lmerModLmerTest")` but it's easy enough to refit).

```
library(lmerTest)
m1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data=ss, REML=FALSE)
m2 <- update(m1, . ~ . - Days + junk1)
m3 <- update(m1, . ~ . - Days + junk2)
cand.set <- list(m1, m2, m3)
aictab(cand.set, modnames=names, second.ord=TRUE, nobs=NULL, sort=TRUE)
```

> Error in aictab.default(cand.set, modnames = names, second.ord = TRUE,  : 
>   Function not yet defined for this object class

The `bbmle::AICctab()` function is a little bit more robust because it relies only on the `logLik` method being defined for a class (by default it gives a table with only the delta-AIC and df)

```
library(bbmle)
AICctab(m1, m2, m3, mnames=names, base=TRUE, weights=TRUE, logLik=TRUE)
##       logLik AICc   dLogLik dAICc  df weight
## Days  -897.0 1802.3   58.2     0.0 4  1     
## junk2 -955.1 1918.5    0.1   116.2 4  <0.001
## junk1 -955.2 1918.7    0.0   116.4 4  <0.001
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Detaching the lmerTest package worked perfectly.