# How to generate an AIC table for GLMs that includes the names of predictor variables

Tags: r, glm, goodness-of-fit

I am running a series of glms using the below code, run in R Markdown. I need the AIC table to include the variable names (not just the name of the model).

```
# Specify the names of predictor variables
predictor_vars <- c("communitiesinpa", "formalprotection", "attitudewildlife", "competitionlivestock", "fenced", "parkresourcescat", "routinepatrols", "mitigationlivestockbarriers", "mitigationcommunityengagement")

# Create all possible combinations of predictor variables
all_combinations <- unlist(lapply(1:length(predictor_vars), function(x) combn(predictor_vars, x, simplify = FALSE)), recursive = FALSE)

# Create an empty list to store the GLM models
models_list <- list()

# Fit GLMs for all combinations and store them in the models_list
for (i in seq_along(all_combinations)) {
  formula_string <- paste("totalthreatscore ~", paste(all_combinations[[i]], collapse = "+"))
  formula_object <- as.formula(formula_string)
  model <- glm(formula_object, data = glmdata, family = Gamma)
  models_list[[i]] <- model
}

# Print the summary of each model
for (i in seq_along(models_list)) {
  cat("Model with predictors:", paste(all_combinations[[i]], collapse = " + "), "\n")
  print(summary(models_list[[i]]))
  cat("\n")
}

AIC_table <- aictab(models_list)

# Display the AIC table
knitr::kable(AIC_table)
```

`aictab` provides the model numbers (i.e., 1 to >500), but does not include the variable names. Can anyone assist with modifying the code to include these?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the variables as `attr`ibute to each model. Demonstrated on `mtcars` with slightly simplified code.

```
predictor_vars <- c("cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", 
                    "gear", "carb")
outcome_var <- "mpg"

models_list <- 
  lapply(seq_along(predictor_vars), \(m) combn(predictor_vars, m, \(x) {
    do.call('glm', list(fo=reformulate(x, outcome_var), data=quote(mtcars), 
                        family=quote(Gamma))) |> `attr<-`('p.vars', x)
    }, simplify=FALSE)) |> unlist(recursive=FALSE)
```

<sup>([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46616150/6574038) elaborates on the use of `do.call` here.)</sup>

The use of `bbmle::AICctab` was recommended[<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55291233/6574038). We can produce character strings out of the *p.vars* using `toString()` and `cbind`.

```
AIC_table <- bbmle::AICctab(models_list, base=TRUE, weights=TRUE, logLik=TRUE)
AIC_table <- cbind(as.data.frame(AIC_table),
                   p.vars=sapply(models_list, attr, 'p.vars') |> 
                     sapply(toString))

knitr::kable(AIC_table)
# |         |    logLik|     AICc|  dLogLik|    dAICc| df|    weight|p.vars |
# |:--------|---------:|--------:|--------:|--------:|--:|---------:|:------|
# |model29  | -67.10019| 143.6819| 30.77475| 0.000000|  4| 0.0701785|cyl    |
# |model126 | -66.19796| 144.7036| 31.67698| 1.021748|  5| 0.0421050|disp   |
# |model41  | -67.72280| 144.9271| 30.15215| 1.245210|  4| 0.0376539|hp     |
# |model129 | -66.35748| 145.0227| 31.51746| 1.340789|  5| 0.0358968|drat   |
# |model333 | -64.95201| 145.2640| 32.92294| 1.582143|  6| 0.0318160|wt     |
# |model65  | -66.68501| 145.6777| 31.18994| 1.995839|  5| 0.0258710|qsec   |
# ...
# |model8  | -93.78769| 194.4325| 4.087253| 50.75066|  3|      0|cyl, disp, hp, drat, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb     |
# |model10 | -94.04827| 194.9537| 3.826675| 51.27182|  3|      0|cyl, disp, hp, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb       |
# |model53 | -93.78669| 197.0549| 4.088254| 53.37300|  4|      0|cyl, disp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb     |
# |model49 | -93.96504| 197.4116| 3.909904| 53.72970|  4|      0|cyl, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb       |
# |model9  | -96.81108| 200.4793| 1.063868| 56.79743|  3|      0|disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb      |
# |model6  | -97.87495| 202.6070| 0.000000| 58.92517|  3|      0|cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb |
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion! I get the following error message after running "AIC_table <- bbmle::AICctab(models_list, base=TRUE, weights=TRUE, logLik=TRUE)"  Error in ICtab(..., mnames = mnames, type = "AICc") : 
  nobs different: must have identical data for all objects. Any ideas about what is wrong?

Comment: @lizanner Do you have missings in the data? `glm` omits cases by list-wise deletion then, and number of observations (nobs) will thus differ in the models.

Comment: Yes, @jay.sf, thank you for identifying that issue. I have resolved that now and the code runs. However, I have an ongoing problem with the AIC table. It is listing the p.vars in the  order in which I enter them into predictor_vars. So, if for example, I enter formalprotection first in the list, that will come up as the first model in the AIC table. If I change it to communitiesinpas first, this will come up as the first model in the AIC table. Any suggestions?

Comment: @lizanner Great you solved it. Not sure if I can follow you and what you expect, best you use my example to explain in an edit to your question.

Comment: predictor_vars <- c("disp", "cyl", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", 
                    "gear", "carb") - I have changed the order of the predictor_vars, so that disp is first and cyl second. If you run the code using this, then the top model has p.vars = disp. If you run the code with "cyl" first in the list of predictor_vars, then the top model with the lowest AICc value, has p.vars = cyl.